# How can I make dual-lines in a JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I'm not sure how much of sense my title does but since you are suppose to have somewhat of a good title this was the best I came up with, so what I actually mean is...

Let's say in theory I've got 10 tabs, and instead of having them all compressed together in 1 line I'd like to split them in 2, so I'd have 5 tabs on the upper side and 5 on the lower.
Example pic: [image: A image of what I tried to explain above]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not clear your question, but there are basic methods for Tabs in the JTabbedPane

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class TabComponentsDemo extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final int tabNumber = 15;
    private final JTabbedPane pane = new JTabbedPane();
    private JMenuItem tabComponentsItem;
    private JMenuItem scrollLayoutItem;

    public TabComponentsDemo(String title) {
        super(title);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        initMenu();
        add(pane);
    }

    public void runTest() {
        pane.removeAll();
        for (int i = 0; i < tabNumber; i++) {
            String title = "Tab " + i;
            pane.add(title, new JLabel(title));
            //initTabComponent(i);
        }
        tabComponentsItem.setSelected(true);
        pane.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.WRAP_TAB_LAYOUT);
        scrollLayoutItem.setSelected(false);
        setSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    /*private void initTabComponent(int i) {
    pane.setTabComponentAt(i, new ButtonTabComponent(pane));
    }*/
    private void initMenu() {//Setting menu
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();//create Options menu        
        tabComponentsItem = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Use TabComponents", true);
        tabComponentsItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_T, InputEvent.ALT_MASK));
        tabComponentsItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (int i = 0; i < pane.getTabCount(); i++) {
                    if (tabComponentsItem.isSelected()) {
                        //initTabComponent(i);
                    } else {
                        pane.setTabComponentAt(i, null);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        scrollLayoutItem = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Set ScrollLayout");
        scrollLayoutItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, InputEvent.ALT_MASK));
        scrollLayoutItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (pane.getTabLayoutPolicy() == JTabbedPane.WRAP_TAB_LAYOUT) {
                    pane.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);
                } else {
                    pane.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.WRAP_TAB_LAYOUT);
                }
            }
        });
        JMenuItem resetItem = new JMenuItem("Reset JTabbedPane");
        resetItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_R, InputEvent.ALT_MASK));
        resetItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                runTest();
            }
        });
        JMenu optionsMenu = new JMenu("Options");
        optionsMenu.add(tabComponentsItem);
        optionsMenu.add(scrollLayoutItem);
        optionsMenu.add(resetItem);
        menuBar.add(optionsMenu);
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
                new TabComponentsDemo("TabComponentsDemo").runTest();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want them all displayed in a single row (which I think is what the latter part of your description indicates...), you'll want to set the tab layout policy to `JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT`.

Here's an [example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/TabLayoutPolicySCROLLTABLAYOUTorWRAPTAPLAYOUT.htm) with an image.